# Kendo grid is not editable, even when set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid

In my code below, I want to set "Qty Shipped" & "Qty Ordered" to be editable. However, those columns are not editable even when set to true.

How would I fix this?

```
<div id="MonthlyTransactionReport"
                 data-role="grid"
                 data-resizable="false"
                 data-navigatable="true"
                 data-pageable="true"
                 pagesize="10"
                 data-scrollable="true"
                 data-sortable="false"
                 data-columns="[
                            { 'field': 'poNumber', 'title': '<b>PO #', 'width': 70, editable: false },
                            { 'field': 'lineNumber', 'title': '<b>Line #', 'width': 65, editable: false },
                            { 'field': 'itemNumber', 'title': '<b>Item #', 'width': 100, editable: false },
                            { 'field': 'itemDesc', 'title': '<b>Description', 'width': 210, editable: false },
                            { 'field': 'qtyOrdered', 'title': '<b>Qty <br> Ordered', 'width': 65, editable: true },
                            { 'field': 'qtyShipped', 'title': '<b>Qty <br> Shipped', 'width': 65, editable: true },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the ["editable" is option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable) of the grid - please check the example below how to enable it:

```
        <div data-role="grid"
             date-scrollable="true"
             data-editable="true"
```

If you need to turn off the editing of given column you can do so using the grid dataSource ["schema.model.fields.field.editable" option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define):

```
schema: {
  model: {
     id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductName: { type: "string", editable: false },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number" }
```